# Expand div to contents outside container on hover

Tags: html, css, layout, hover

I have a `div` which often has contents larger than itself. The overflow should be hidden:

[image]

However, when the user hovers over the `div`, it should expand to fit the contents. It should be layered over its container if necessary. The container div should not be expanded. The top-right of the div should remain in the same position on the page.

I have tried `position: relative`, various float values and so on, but have had no luck.

How can I achieve this layout?

Comment: I do not have an error with existing code; I just don't know which properties to use.

Comment: @Paulie_D Surrounding elements should be unaffected; I updated the question with this info.

Comment: "[...] when the user hovers over the div, it should expand to fit the contents. It should be layered over its container if necessary [...]"

Answer (score 0):

You would need to position the contents (a paragraph perhaps) absolutely within the div.

The amend the height and overflow on hover.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  height: 1.2em;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
div p {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
div:hover {
  overflow: visible;
}
div:hover p {
  height: auto;
  white-space: normal
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, maxime.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this very nearly works. However, the expanded `p` does not float above all other page elements. It should go over its container and its container's container, etc.

Comment: Probably needs a higher Z-index that's all. You'd have to make a proper demo of your actual issue in that case.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure to understand very well your question but
Do you have fixed width and fixed height on your div? then

```
div{
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
div:hover{
  width:200px; 
  height:auto; 
  overflow:auto
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! **This is really a comment, not an answer.**  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!

Comment: sorry @Paulie_D, that was my answer and not a comment.

Comment: Then perhaps you need to reformat your "answer" to take out the comments and questions and demonstrate how this solution would actually work.